# iOS Swift: Eliminate trailing zeroes for CGFloat

Tags: ios, swift

I have float value that ends in .0 or .5 (for example 10.0 or 10.5). If it ends in .0 I would like to eliminate the trailing zero. What is the easiest way to do this in Swift?

```
func myFunction() {
    var string = pickerData[picker.selectedRowInComponent(0)]
    var float = ((string as NSString).floatValue - 45) / 2
    label.text = float.description
}
```

Comment: Converting it to Int?

Comment: In instances where the number does not end in a trailing zero I would like to preserve the decimal. Converting to an Int would not do that.

Comment: `label.text = (float == floorf(float)) ? "\(Int(float))" : "\(float)"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use NSNumberFormatter() to format your numbers as follow:

```
extension Double {
    var formatted:String {
        let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
        // you can set the minimum fraction digits to 0
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
        // and set the maximum fraction digits to 1
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
        return formatter.stringFromNumber(self) ?? ""
    }
}

10.5.formatted  //  "10.5"
10.0.formatted  //  "10"
```

In your case it would look like this:

```
label.text = float.formatted
```

Comment: you should choose better names for your vars. I would change float to  myFloat and string to myString.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I usually rename variables for the sake of posting. But I will take your advice.

Comment: How would I return a Float instead of a String here?